# Не могу подключиться к локальной бд

Tags: c#, sql-server

Не могу подключиться к созданной на ms sqlExpress бд.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот я подключаюсь к созданной бд в менджмент студии.

Пробую подключаться vs студии

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server = .\SQLEXPRESS; Database = Proxy; Trusted_Connection = True;"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(connection.State);
    }
```

Консоль пишет что соединение закрыто.

Пробовал также подключаться через созданный конфигурационный xml файл.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Proxy;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Подключение в коде

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Console.WriteLine(connectionString);

Конфигуратор в итоге возвращает пустую строку.
У мне воообще никаких предположений что тут за дичь, точички или запятой где-то не хватает или хренота, 2й день не получается ничего.
Подскажите пожалуйста хоть куда копать.

Comment: Что именно пишет консоль? Покажите код подключения к базе, а не код доставание строки из конфига.

Comment: А, туплю. Соединение надо открывать вручную. Напишите connection.Open().

Comment: Закрывать не надо, это за вас using сделает

Comment: Блен, спасибо! Странно что я этот момент не нашел не на Метаните не в msdn.

Comment: Очень странно, что не нашли, первый же пример из документации содержит то, что вам нужно. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8#examples

Comment: @PashaPash ответом оформите?

Comment: Конечно, только я не знаю как это сделать) Чет интуитивно не понятно.

Comment: @Николай что именно вам непонятно?